# How to create 3 spliters in windows Form

Tags: c#

Now I am develop one project with windows form (C#).
and I want to separate my form into 3 parts.
So, can anyone tell me how to create 3 spliters in window form (C#)?

Comment: I use [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) for layout on my forms

Comment: You can use the [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.100))

Answer (score 4):

3 parts require only 2 splitters.  Drop a SplitContainer on a SplitContainer panel.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how to use 3 images (normal, over and down) as a button in window form.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with this question.  Ask another question by clicking the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use [Split Container Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0w5ctby.aspx) or [Table layout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx.aspx)